# Can I select only one checkbox out of multiple checkboxes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to allow the user to check only one checkbox out of more than five checkboxes. The checkboxes are having the same name and different values. I need to store these values and retrieve from database. Does Jquery support this feature?
I am a newbie...

Answer (score 2):

Better to use radio buttons in this case. They are meant to serve this purpose. Selecting only an item from this case.

If checkbox is a strict requirement then you can do this with jQuery. You have to unselect all the checboxes first and then check the one which is clicked.

Comment: Sorry Answer...Its helps me lot

Answer (score 1):

use radiobuttons.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp --> scroll down to *Radio Buttons*

Comment: Thanks for your comments both of you.But I adviced to use the checkbox only.Please help me in the means of checkboxes....Thanks in advance...

Comment: the one who adviced you that gave you bad advice

Answer (score 0):

When you dont wont radio buttons here is a jquery solution:

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox.myCheckboxGroup');
checkboxes.click(function(){
  var self = this;
  checkboxes.each(function(){
    if(this!=self) this.checked = ''
  })
})
```